# select random items from an array

Tags: python

```
import os, glob, numpy as np

files = glob.glob('*.jpg')
indices = np.array([i for i,j in enumerate(files)])
selected_indices = np.random.choice(indices,500,replace=False)
print files[selected_indices]
```

I could not convert indices into files. What's good way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `glob.glob('*.jpg')` returns a list and python does not support:

`list[array_of_indices]`

Instead, do it as:

```
selected_indices = list(np.random.choice(indices,500,replace=False))
print [files[i] for i in selected_indices]
```

However, there is a **much** better way of doing it. ***Please*** see [**@OlehPrypin's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454043/randomly-select-files-in-numpy/23454126#23454126)

Answer (score 5):

#### Do it the proper way!

```
import glob
import random

files = glob.glob('*.jpg')
selected_files = random.sample(files, 500)
print(selected_files)
```

Both of the methods have a problem when `Sample larger than population`. So instead of `500` we can use `min(500, len(files))` if needed.